# New models present after upgrading Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.0.1

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

As an exercise in our organization, we are upgrading our API's to .NET 5 and along with it, all the dependent NuGet packages. During this I observed a strange behavior on my Swagger Schema/Models (currently I'm running the latest and the greatest versions of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations i.e. 6.0.1) where in additional models were enlisted which were not present during 4.0.1 version.

To give a background, I've multiple Patch methods across multiple controllers which has JsonPatchDocument as a parameter:

[image]

and here is the swagger which additional models which gets generated:

[image]

So here are my questions:

1. Is this the indented behavior when Swagger moved to OpenApi 3.0?
2. Is this model really needed? Coz, when we generate the client, it produces models with obnoxiously long names.
3. If this is really not needed, is there a way we can suppress this?
4. As a closure, I had a custom schema definition which use to work before upgrade, which was something like this:

[image]

This was used to shorten the model names, but now after the upgrade, the same code throws following errors (which is inter-related to the patch operations):

[image]

Changing the above code to following code, gets rid of the error, but with this approach, I cannot shorten the model names.

```
c.CustomSchemaIds(t => t.FullName);
```

With the limited documentation, its pretty difficult to deduce, what the issue is and help in this regards is very much appreciated.

Thank you.